# Preg_replace match on word boundery and not in link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a regex to match words on boundery and because text is in html I need to avoid words that are in `<a>here more words</a>`.

My regex for now is: `/\bword\b/u`

Example text:

```
<p>Example lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur <a href="">porta lorem nec</a> tortor laoreet gravida.</p>
```

Searching for word `lorem` should be replaced only at the beginning, not in `<a>`.

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use some **dark powers** like the following:

`<a[^>]*>.*?</a\s*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\blorem\b`

Let's break it down:

```
<a[^>]*>            # match an opening "a" tag
.*?                 # match anything ungreedy until ...
</a\s*>             # match a closing "a" tag
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # skip it
|                   # or
\blorem\b           # match lorem with boundaries
```

So basically we first skip all `a` tags, then we match `lorem`.

<kbd>[**See a working demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sY5wL4)</kbd>

Comment: You don't need to check that `lorem` is inside `<a..>..</a>` tags.

Comment: The goal of the first part of the pattern is to avoid <a> tags, because `lorem` can be inside. But to check that the regex engine must go from `<a\b` until it met `</a>`, whether or not `lorem` is present. Conclusion, no need to check if `lorem` is here or not. You can write: `<a\b[^>]*>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\blorem\b` instead.

Comment: In other words, you can skip all `<a>` tags of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`/u` in your regexp may be inappropriate or unneeded. it's usually to indicate unicode in PHP but for example not allowed in JavaScript.
Or it may be that you're using `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all` in your PHP