# PHP preg_replace regex exclude html <a> tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The goal would be:
I have some titles. I would like to turn the titles in a text to link. BUT when it is a link, I DON'T want to change. I am looking for the right regex.

I have a PHP code like this:

```
foreach($res as $r) {
  $new_string = '<a href="#" onclick="getMarkers(1,\\\' \\\',1);locate('.$r->latitude.','.$r->longitude.','.$r->zoom.','.$r->id.',0);">$0</a>';
  $introduction = (preg_replace("/\b$r->title\b(?![^<>]*(?:<|$))/i",$new_string,$introduction))
}
```

This part of my code doesn't work:

```
preg_replace("/\b$r->title\b(?![^<>]*(?:<|$))/i",$new_string,$introduction)
```

The problem is:
This regex also change the avilable links what is in  HTML tag.

Thank you for everybody patiente and I am wainting for the answers!

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**:
I would like to say thank you for [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) for this fantastic link!

*My solutions is:*

```
 $introduction = (preg_replace("/[^>]*>.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|$r->title/im",$new_string,$introduction));
```

Thanks for everybody! :)

Comment: Please add what the full title (with surrounding tags) looks like that you want to replace and maybe the already linkes title that you do not want to replace.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the html you're trying to use.

Comment: _“I DON'T want to change”_ – be yourself, stay yourself.

Comment: You might apply [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913029).

Answer (score 0):

This may be an overly simple solution, but you can use a negative lookbehind to make sure that the url does not have a `href=` in front of it.  If not, then capture it with whatever domain REGEX you prefer.

I used a pretty clunky domain name validator, so this is going to look like a mess, but I'll explain it.

```
$string = 'This is just a bunch of random text. <A HREF="http://www.google.com">google</A> This is 
just a bunch of random text. http://www.yahoo.com This is just a bunch of random text. 
<A HREF="http://www.cnn.com">cnn.com</A> This is just a bunch of random text. http://www.msn.com This 
is just a bunch of random text. ';

$string = preg_replace('~(?<!href="|href=\'|href=)((?:http(?:s)?://)(?:www\.)?[-A-Z0-9.]+(?:\.[-A-Z0-9]{2,4})[-A-Z0-9_./]?(?:[-A-Z0-9#?/]+)?)~i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);

print $string;
```

This outputs:

```
This is just a bunch of random text. <A HREF="http://www.google.com">google</A> This is 
just a bunch of random text. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a> This is just a bunch of random text. 
<A HREF="http://www.cnn.com">cnn.com</A> This is just a bunch of random text. <a href="http://www.msn.com">http://www.msn.com</a> This 
is just a bunch of random text.
```

Okay, now an explanation of the REGEX:

```
(?<!href="|href=\'|href=)    ((?:http(?:s)?://)(?:www\.)?[-A-Z0-9.]+(?:\.[-A-Z0-9]{2,4})[-A-Z0-9_./]?(?:[-A-Z0-9#?/]+)?)
              ^                                                ^
              1                                                2
```

There really only 2 parts to this:

1. This is a negative lookbehind which makes sure that the url does not have `href="`, `href='` (escaped, of course) or `href=` in front of it.
2. The next part is just a domain validation script.  You can use something far simpler here if you'd prefer.