# Regex: How to find all occurrences of the string in the text but not those that are inside <textarea> tag

Tags: php, regex

I parce page html body as string.

I am looking for parent `/(\[ID\])/iU`. I can find it well no problem. But I want to skip all if it is inside `<textarea>` or `value` attribute of `<input>`.

Example

```
<p>This is your id: [ID]</p>
<p>Please edit it here : <textarea>My id is [ID]<br> Some html because it is WYSIWYG</textarea></p>
<p>Please edit it here : <input type="text" value="My id is [ID]!" /></p>
```

I want to find first occurrence of [ID] but not second and third.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to use `preg_match_all` and catch all it finds into `$matches` variable.

Comment: You should not use regular expressions to parse HTML in the first place. You said you want to skip something , please be little specific so others can help you out. Adding an expected output on your question will really help.

Comment: I thought I explained everything. I want preg_match_all find all [ID] placeholder but not those that are in `textarea`.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov With some advanced regex-fu you might use [this](http://regex101.com/r/hS3vM8). I've used the similar technique [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913029) which includes some explanation. Try also to take a look at [this reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618).

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no, and no... HTML parsing is not best performed using regular expressions -- much better to use [specialized libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699911/get-text-between-html-tags). For example, there is the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library and to extract content between  tags, you'll need to:

#### Use a DOM parser for your approach..

```
<?php
$html='<p>This is your id: [ID]</p>
<p>Please edit it here : <textarea>My id is [ID]<br> Some html because it is WYSIWYG</textarea></p>
<p>Please edit it here : <input type="text" value="My id is [ID]!" /></p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $ptag)
{
    $flag=0;

    foreach($ptag->getElementsByTagName('textarea') as $v1)
    {
        $flag=1;
    }
    foreach($ptag->getElementsByTagName('input') as $v1)
    {
        $flag=1;
    }
    if(!$flag)
    {
        preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\]/', $ptag->nodeValue, $matches);
        echo $matches[1][0]; //"prints" ID
    }

}
```

#### Alternate regular expression way..

```
$text = preg_grep('\[ID\]', $html);
if ($text) { # '[ID]' is found in $html
    print_r($text[0]);
} else { # not found
    # deal with it as you will
}
```

Comment: But I do not know what would be an HTML structure за the document. I only know that I need to find a and replace string without replacing it inside `textarea`.

Comment: Your question states you're dealing with HTML.

Comment: @hd1, Are you going to expand the answer on how to deal with the above problem using a HTML parser or not ? If not , the above answer you provided is deemed to be a _comment_.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Is that enough of an example?

Comment: Yes, because he said he wasn't using HTML -- see OPs first comment

Comment: The question is not how to use preg functions in php. I use 

`if(preg_match_all("/\[ID\]/iU", $body, $matches)){}`. This I can handle. But this also finds [ID] inside `<textarea>` but I do not want that.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov, Try the DOM way suggested by hd1 instead and be patient ! **We are not here for that , we are here to help**

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, that was not irritation or anger. I am sorry. This simply way I talk without intending to offend anyone.

Comment: Quote myself: But I do not know what would be an HTML structure of the document. So I cannot use `$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')` because this placeholder may be in any part of the text I do not know where. In fact it is even more complex. 

I used [ID] as example to simplify but placeholder is like this `[PAID={"id":"1,2,3","other json data"}]Some text to hide[/PAID]`. And there may be HTML inside that pattern. 

And it may be inserted in to any input field or even insite template php file.

Answer (score 0):

How I did solve the problem. I have page HTML source in `$body` variable. So before run my search and replace.

```
$pattern = '/\[ID\]/iU';
$replace = array();
if(preg_match_all('/(<textarea(.*)<\/textarea>)/isU', $body, $areas, PREG_SET_ORDER))
{
    foreach($areas As $area)
    {
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $area[0]))
        {
            $replace[] = array(
                'src' => '{{TA_'.md5($area[0]).'}}',
                'dst' => $area[0]
            );
            $body = str_replace($area[0], '{{TA_'.md5($area[0]).'}}', $body);
        }
    }
}
if(preg_match_all('/(<input([^>]*)>)/isU', $body, $inputs, PREG_SET_ORDER))
{
    foreach($inputs As $input)
    {
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $input[0]))
        {
            $replace[] = array(
                'src' => '{{IP_'.md5($input[0]).'}}',
                'dst' => $input[0]
            );
            $body = str_replace($input[0], '{{IP_'.md5($input[0]).'}}', $body);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I finished all my replacements and parsing I do this.

```
foreach($replace AS $rep)
{
    $body = str_replace($rep['src'], $rep['dst'], $body);
}
```